# How to have an array type in C binding?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to port this code :

```
struct SoundIoChannelLayout {
    const char *name;
    int channel_count;
    enum SoundIoChannelId channels[SOUNDIO_MAX_CHANNELS];
};
```

But i don't know how to define the type of `channels`, and I know that I can't use a pointer because the final struct size won't be the same.

Comment: [The docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/c_bindings/fun.html) talk about StaticArray, and it even has syntax sugar for its definition. I haven't tried to write the resulting code, but that should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to auto-generate it using [crystal_lib](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal_lib):

```
$ cd crystal_lib
$ cat examples/soundio.cr
@[Include("soundio/soundio.h", prefix: %w(SoundIo))]
@[Link("soundio")]
lib LibSoundio
end
$ crystal src/main.cr -- examples/soundio.cr > soundio.cr
```

So it looks like this:

```
@[Link("soundio")]
lib LibSoundio
  MAX_CHANNELS = 24

  struct ChannelLayout
    name : LibC::Char*
    channel_count : LibC::Int
    channels : ChannelId[MAX_CHANNELS]
  end

  enum ChannelId
    Invalid = 0
    FrontLeft = 1
    FrontRight = 2
    FrontCenter = 3
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

*Note:* you may need to update resulted file manually because crystal_lib is still experimental.